# Customize Appendix package

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

I need to customize my Appendix but can not figure out how.

I need:

1. Entry in my Main ToC at the beginning of the document generated with `\tableofcontents`
2. Change the Name of Appendices displayed in the ToC to the German "Anhang"
3. Insert the Appendix after my References

   - Titel Page with "Anhang"
   - ToC showing each Chapter/section of the Appendix and page number

What would be the best way to do this using the Appendix package?

Thanks!

EDIT: I need to edit the MWE so that the entries that currently show up in the Main ToC do not show any more, only the Entry: "Anhang". The first Page after the appendix Titel Page should be a separate ToC that shows the entries of the appendix and the page number.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,ngerman]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix} % Anhang 

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\appendixname}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\appendixname}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents %Inhaltsverzeichnis 
\newpage 
\section{Section}
Test 123
\newpage 
\subsection{SubSection 1} 
Test 123
\newpage 
\begin{appendices} 
\section{Test}

TEST 123

\section{Test 2}

TEST 123


\section{Test 3}

TEST 123


\end{appendices} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable document? The translation, anyway, should be done automatically with the `ngerman` option of `babel`.

Comment: @TeXnician: As I don't really speak german, I  don't know the differences. Anyway, I've changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use the automatically loaded package `tocbasic` to define an additional ToC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel}

%%% see: https://komascript.de/comment/5578#comment-5578 (Markus Kohm)
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={Inhalt des Anhangs},% Titel des Verzeichnisses
]{atoc}% Dateierweiterung (a=appendix, toc=table of contents)

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixtoc}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{% damit es auch ohne hyperref funktioniert
    \hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}%
  }%
}
\ifundefinedorrelax{ext@toc}{%
  \newcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}
  \renewcommand{\addtocentrydefault}[3]{%
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@toc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }
}{}
\makeatother
%%%

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \addpart{\appendixname}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vfill\vfill
  \clearpage
  \useappendixtoc
  \listofatocs
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\usekomafont{sectionentry}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\appendix
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you switch to `scrreprt` you can use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{babel}

%%% see: https://komascript.de/comment/5578#comment-5578 (Markus Kohm)
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={Inhalt des Anhangs},% Titel des Verzeichnisses
]{atoc}% Dateierweiterung (a=appendix, toc=table of contents)

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixtoc}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{% damit es auch ohne hyperref funktioniert
    \hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}%
  }%
}
\ifundefinedorrelax{ext@toc}{%
  \newcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}
  \renewcommand{\addtocentrydefault}[3]{%
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@toc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }
}{}
\makeatother
%%%

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix{
  \cleardoublepage
  \addpart{\appendixname}
  \useappendixtoc
  \listofatocs
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\renewcommand\partpagestyle{empty}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\usekomafont{chapterentry}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\appendix
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Dots between all TOC entries and their page numbers:**

If you want to add dots between the chapter entries and their page numbers in **all TOCs** insert the following line in your preambel:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{chapter,part}
```

If you want to add these dots **only in the appendix TOC** use either

```
\xapptocmd\appendix{
  \cleardoublepage
  \addpart{\appendixname}
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{chapter}% <- added
  \useappendixtoc
  \listofatocs
}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

or

```
\xapptocmd\appendix{
  \cleardoublepage
  \addpart{\appendixname}
  \KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrywithdots}% <- added
  \useappendixtoc
  \listofatocs
}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Comment: Fantastic, this nearly does it for me. Only problem I see in my document is, that the Font size of "Anhang" in the first ToC is slightly bigger than the rest of the entries. In your MWE this does not to be a problem. I guess changing "\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\usekomafont{sectionentry}}" could help, but I tried subsectionentry and instead of sectionentry but it would not do anything.

Comment: I figured that it has to do with the fact that I am using report class in my actual document and not the article class. Is there a possible fix for this?

Comment: Change `\usekomafont{sectionentry}` to `\usekomafont{chapterentry}`. But there are some additional changes needed. See the second example in my updated answer.

Comment: Great Stuff, Thank You! Just a quick follow up: Is there a way to have dots as a filler from entry name to page number in the appendix ToC?

Comment: I have added a suggestion for the dots at the end of my answer.